# Validate name with email in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data frame like below having `name` and `email` column.

```
df <- data.frame(name=c("maay,bhtr","nsgu,nhuts thang","affat,nurfs","nukhyu,biyts","ngyst,muun","nsgyu,noon","utrs guus,book","thum,cryant","mumt,cant","bhan,btan","khtri,ntuk","ghaan,rstu","shaan,btqaan","nhue,bjtraan","wutys,cyun","hrtsh,jaan"),
      email=c("maay.bhtr@email.com","nsgu.nhuts@gmail.com","asfa.1234@gmail.com","nukhyu.biyts@gmail.com","ngyst.muun@gmail.com","nsgyu.noon@gmail.com","utrs.book@hotmail.com","thum.cryant@live.com","mumt.cant@gmail.com","bhan.btan@gmail.com","khtri.ntuk@gmail.c.om","chang.lee@gmail.com","shaan.btqaan@gmail.com","nhue.bjtraan@gmail.com","wutys.cyun@gmailcom","hrtsh.jaan@gmail.com"))
```

I am looking for a function by which i can check if the first name or last name matches with mail id then mutate new column to true.

[image: The output should be like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try

```
within(
  df,
  consistent <- mapply(
    function(x, y) 1 - any(mapply(grepl, x, y) | mapply(grepl, x, y)),
    strsplit(name, ","),
    strsplit(gsub("@.*", "", email), "\\.")
  )
)
```

which gives

```
               name                  email consistent
1         maay,bhtr    maay.bhtr@email.com          0
2  nsgu,nhuts thang   nsgu.nhuts@gmail.com          0
3       affat,nurfs    asfa.1234@gmail.com          1
4      nukhyu,biyts nukhyu.biyts@gmail.com          0
5        ngyst,muun   ngyst.muun@gmail.com          0
6        nsgyu,noon   nsgyu.noon@gmail.com          0
7    utrs guus,book  utrs.book@hotmail.com          0
8       thum,cryant   thum.cryant@live.com          0
9         mumt,cant    mumt.cant@gmail.com          0
10        bhan,btan    bhan.btan@gmail.com          0
11       khtri,ntuk  khtri.ntuk@gmail.c.om          0
12       ghaan,rstu    chang.lee@gmail.com          1
13     shaan,btqaan shaan.btqaan@gmail.com          0
14     nhue,bjtraan nhue.bjtraan@gmail.com          0
15       wutys,cyun    wutys.cyun@gmailcom          0
16       hrtsh,jaan   hrtsh.jaan@gmail.com          0
```

Answer (score 1):

In Base `R` we can utilize `Map()` and `sapply()` to loop through your list and create a logical vector to then append to your df:

Since this code included a lot of nested apply statements let me try to explain whats ging on. The code is probably best understood when starting from the inside.

```
# t is the strsplit() names column

strsplit(df[,1], ",")

# this next line checks if the names occur in the email address 

grepl(t, y, fixed = T) 

# this statement wrapped in sapply returns a list with each entry containing two true/false statements for first and last name
# the sapply() statement above allows us to do exactly that for every row
# lastly we convert this list into a single true/false for each df entry
```

**Code:**

```
a <- sapply(Map(function(x, y){
  sapply(x, function(t){
    grepl(t, y, fixed = T)
  })}
  , strsplit(df[,1], ","), df[, 2]), function(p){
  if(any(p)){
    T
  } else {
    F
  }
})

# result 

cbind(df, a)

               name                  email     a
1         maay,bhtr    maay.bhtr@email.com  TRUE
2  nsgu,nhuts thang   nsgu.nhuts@gmail.com  TRUE
3       affat,nurfs    asfa.1234@gmail.com FALSE
4      nukhyu,biyts nukhyu.biyts@gmail.com  TRUE
5        ngyst,muun   ngyst.muun@gmail.com  TRUE
6        nsgyu,noon   nsgyu.noon@gmail.com  TRUE
7    utrs guus,book  utrs.book@hotmail.com  TRUE
8       thum,cryant   thum.cryant@live.com  TRUE
9         mumt,cant    mumt.cant@gmail.com  TRUE
10        bhan,btan    bhan.btan@gmail.com  TRUE
11       khtri,ntuk  khtri.ntuk@gmail.c.om  TRUE
12       ghaan,rstu    chang.lee@gmail.com FALSE
13     shaan,btqaan shaan.btqaan@gmail.com  TRUE
14     nhue,bjtraan nhue.bjtraan@gmail.com  TRUE
15       wutys,cyun    wutys.cyun@gmailcom  TRUE
16       hrtsh,jaan   hrtsh.jaan@gmail.com  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as follows - code commented below.

```
df <- data.frame(name=c("maay,bhtr","nsgu,nhuts thang","affat,nurfs","nukhyu,biyts","ngyst,muun","nsgyu,noon","utrs guus,book","thum,cryant","mumt,cant","bhan,btan","khtri,ntuk","ghaan,rstu","shaan,btqaan","nhue,bjtraan","wutys,cyun","hrtsh,jaan"),
                 email=c("maay.bhtr@email.com","nsgu.nhuts thang@gmail.com","asfa.1234@gmail.com","nukhyu.biyts@gmail.com","ngyst.muun@gmail.com","nsgyu.noon@gmail.com","utrs guus.book@hotmail.com","thum.cryant@live.com","mumt.cant@gmail.com","bhan.btan@gmail.com","khtri.ntuk@gmail.c.om","chang.lee@gmail.com","shaan.btqaan@gmail.com","nhue.bjtraan@gmail.com","wutys.cyun@gmailcom","hrtsh.jaan@gmail.com"))


library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
## extract all of the names any string of letters unbroken by a space or punctuation or number
names <- str_extract_all(df$name, "[A-Za-z]*") %>% 
  ## make a matrix out of the names
  do.call(rbind, .) %>% 
  ## turn the names into a data frame
  as.data.frame() 

## some of the columns have all "" in them, find which ones are all ""
w <- sapply(names, function(x)all(x == ""))
## if any of the columns are all "" then ...
if(any(w)){
  ## remove those columns from the dataset
  names <- names[,-which(w)]  
}

## add email into this dataset that has the individual names
names$email <- df$email

library(tidyr)
## pipe the names dataset (which has individual names and an e-mail address)
out <- names %>% 
  ## switch from wide to long format
  pivot_longer(-email, names_to="V", values_to="n") %>% 
  ## create consistent = 1 if the name is not detected in the e-mail
  mutate(consistent = !str_detect(email, n)) %>% 
  ## group the data by e-mail
  group_by(email) %>% 
  ## take the maximum of consistent by group
  ## this will be 1 if any of the names are not detected in the e-mail
  summarise(consistent = max(consistent)) %>% 
  ## join back together with the original data
  left_join(df) %>%
  ## change the variable ordering back
  select(name, email, consistent)

out 
# # A tibble: 16 x 3
#    name             email                      consistent
#    <chr>            <chr>                           <int>
# 1  affat,nurfs      asfa.1234@gmail.com                 1
# 2  bhan,btan        bhan.btan@gmail.com                 0
# 3  ghaan,rstu       chang.lee@gmail.com                 1
# 4  hrtsh,jaan       hrtsh.jaan@gmail.com                0
# 5  khtri,ntuk       khtri.ntuk@gmail.c.om               0
# 6  maay,bhtr        maay.bhtr@email.com                 0
# 7  mumt,cant        mumt.cant@gmail.com                 0
# 8  ngyst,muun       ngyst.muun@gmail.com                0
# 9  nhue,bjtraan     nhue.bjtraan@gmail.com              0
# 10 nsgu,nhuts thang nsgu.nhuts thang@gmail.com          0
# 11 nsgyu,noon       nsgyu.noon@gmail.com                0
# 12 nukhyu,biyts     nukhyu.biyts@gmail.com              0
# 13 shaan,btqaan     shaan.btqaan@gmail.com              0
# 14 thum,cryant      thum.cryant@live.com                0
# 15 utrs guus,book   utrs guus.book@hotmail.com          0
# 16 wutys,cyun       wutys.cyun@gmailcom                 0
#
```

Note, I had to change two of the values of e-mail in your dataset to match the image you posted.